# ContentOffset doesn't do anything to UITextView the first time

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm trying to have a UIViewController to display some text centered vertically in a UITextView.  When app is launched, the text is aligned to the top.  But if I try to select some text, the text would then move to the center vertically.  It seems like setting contentOffset doesn't do anything at the first time, unless there's some action to trigger it to readjust the layout (like selecting some text in my scenario).

Also when I log the values of height, size, contentHeight and topCorrect, the values from the first call is the same as the second call.  So I'm getting the same value but UITextView somehow is not responding to the contentOffset the very first time.

I even tried moving the logic to viewDidLayoutSubviews() and viewDidAppear().  I had the same result.  So I don't think it's a problem of having the logic in the wrong place.

I think some people have success with it on iOS 7 and Obj-C.  I'm trying get it running on iOS 8 and Swift.

Any suggestion or help would be very much appreciated.

> class PageContentViewController : UIViewController {
>
> ```
> @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
>
> override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
>     super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
>     self.textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 16.0, 0, 16.0)
>     let height = self.textView.bounds.size.height
>     let size = CGSizeMake(self.textView.frame.width, CGFloat.max)
>     var contentHeight = self.textView.sizeThatFits(size).height
>     var topCorrect = (height - contentHeight * self.textView.zoomScale) / 2.0
>     topCorrect = topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect;
>     self.textView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -topCorrect), animated: false)
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: This sounds like a bug. File a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com.